# How to add an object from another class

Tags: java

I've been using StackOverflow for a while now but this is my first question, so please exchuse me if something comes or seems not up to par.

I'd like to create a JPanel object (here referred to as 'panel') in a different class (ClassFrom) and then have it show in another JFrame object (here referred to as 'frame') in another class (ClassTo) but there seems to be something off with what I have so far since the JPanel 'panel' won't show in the JFrame 'frame' when the JLabel is clicked.

Could anyone out there please look at my code and please help me out where possible. I would like  Will really appreciate.

Heres my code.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

// The Class with the JFame that gets the components from ClassFrom

public class ClassTo {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("The JFrame");
    ClassFrom classFrom = new ClassFrom();

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // This is where there seems to be a problem
        frame.add(classFrom.contentMethod());
    }
}

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

// The Class with the components to be added to the JFrame in ClassTo

public class ClassFrom {
    public static void contentMethod() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Try Label");

        panel.add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Always copy/paste error & exception output.  If you do that, I'll vote to reopen.  Put it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17895430/edit).

Comment: Question is **on hold** so I can not give the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with a static method trying to access instance variables. Declare frame and classFrom as static or in your main method to solve the compilation error.
Edit: As Ingo pointed out change the return type of contentMethod to JPanel and return that panel so it can be added to the frame variable.

Comment: `static` is rarely the right way to go, and this is not one of the rare occasions.

Comment: Well it is obviously some code for understanding language concepts. Only pointing out the elegant solution does not necessarily help learning.

Comment: 'bad design' is not the same thing as 'not elegant'.  Without further caveats or warnings attached to the mention of `static`, that is a -1.

Comment: Downvote me all day long if you wish, I still think it is an helpful answer. Not every answer needs to dig into design, especially when the focus of the question is so far from a design problem but circles around compile errors when learning basic language concepts.

Comment: I upvoted you to make good for it, yet you should also outline the other misconception of the OP: one cannot pass the result of a void method to another method.

Comment: Did not spot that directly, thanks for that.